# Using CKEeditor blockquote without tag p

Tags: ckeditor

In CKEditor, When I use block quote in tool bar, it will be like

```
<blockquote>
  <p></p>
</blockquote>
```

How to remove the tag `<p></p>` in block quote?

Or how to replace the `<p></p>` with `<pre></pre>`?

Answer (score 0):

This code add filter to editor to change the 'p' tag to 'pre' tag as long as the 'p tag is within a 'bloquote' block.

```
 CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
    {
        var editor = ev.editor;
        var dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor,
        htmlFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.htmlFilter;

        htmlFilter.addRules(
        {
            elements:
            {
                $: function (element) {
                    var parent = element.parent;

                    if (element.name == 'p') {
                        if (parent && parent.name.toLowerCase()=='blockquote') {
                            element.name="pre";
                        } 
                    } 

                    return element;
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

See a example:

https://jsfiddle.net/z6y8q6rm/4/

Comment: Can you add some additional explanation like where this code should be placed and what the code actually does?